# 'hue' in seaborn plot and x-axis location

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I have a dataset with 'Counts' from several 'Items' per animal, for totally 291 animals.
The data has been acquired at days 4, 10,21 and 60, an (edited) `df.to_dense()` looks like this

```
    Animal  Day Item Counts
0   04A     4   11   11
1   04A     4   12    6
2   04A     4   16   26
3   04A     4   20   28
4   04A     4   21   16
[...]
286 60C     60  18   43
287 60C     60  20   69
288 60C     60  21   93
289 60C     60  23   55
290 60C     60  24  114
```

I would like to plot the data nicely, with seaborn.
For this I do `sns.boxplot(data=df, x='Day', y='Counts')` which gives me the plot below.

[image: simple boxplot]

Now I'd like to show the boxplots for the single animals and thought to just add the 'hue' parameter, like so: `sns.boxplot(data=df, x='Day', y='Counts', hue='Animal')`.

[image: boxplot with hue]

The values are now nicely grouped, as I would have expected it, but they are not really aligned to the x-label.
Maye I understand the `hue` parameter wrong, but I'd like to split the day-points into the different animals and show them (center-)aligned to the x-label.

Any tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: I guess the plot itself is correct, right? The only issue is that it leaves the space for *all* animals for each day, while in your case it seems not all animals occur at every day, leaving a hole in the plot. This can afaik not be handled via seaborn and the hue parameter, so the idea would be to create the boxplots manually by grouping the dataframe.

Comment: The plot is correct, I've also seen that seaborn seems to leave some space for all animals. When I do `df.groupby(by=['Day', 'Animal'])['Counts'].describe()` I get a nice overview of the grouped data, but would now like to plot that...